# Change Font Size of all UI Elements using Static Resource from App.xaml in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm need to change the font size of all text across the application.

I have tried doing as follows, but that doesn't work:-

```xml
<Style x:Key="fontsize" TargetType="{x:Type FrameworkElement}">
    <Setter Property="Control.FontSize" Value="20"/>
</Style>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type FrameworkElement}" BasedOn="{StaticResource fontsize}"/>
```

When I try setting as follows then that works fine but doesn't get applied to all elements & needs to apply that for all different types of elements aperately.

```xml
<Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource fontsize}"/>
<Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource fontsize}"/>
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource fontsize}"/>
<Style TargetType="MenuItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource fontsize}"/>
<Style TargetType="DatePicker" BasedOn="{StaticResource fontsize}"/>
```

Also I would like to ask that, is there a way that I can override the Global Style for a particular element, like Heading text should be of different size on a user control?

Comment: How about just setting `FontSize="20"` on the MainWindow?

Answer (score 0):

in App.xaml

```
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
        </Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a global style for the window in App.xaml.

```
    <Application.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="WindowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
            <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
```

and set that style for the required windows.

```
<Window x:Class="YourNamespace.MainWindow"  Style="{StaticResource WindowStyle}".....>
```

for overriding the style for a usercontrol

```
           <local:UserControl1>
                <local:UserControl1.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="UserControl">
                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10"/>
                    </Style>
                </local:UserControl1.Style> 
            </local:UserControl1>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two controls this involves.
You're maybe thinking "hey what about this cell or that calendar".
Their templates show text in a textblock.
When you set Header on a menuitem or content on a label, you get a textblock generated.

You therefore "only" need to set style on both textblock and textbox:

```
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                   <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Having said that.

As Clemens pointed out.

The Font size and styling dependency properties are marked as inherits, so if you just have mainwindow then you could just set on that.

It's not just "obvious" that a label ends up with a textblock in it when you set content though. Similarly a menuitem and header. Hence I thought it worth posting this answer.